# Laser beam with 50/50 photons right and left circularly polarised

Tags: photons, polarization

If I had a laser beam with 50 % left circular polarised and 50 % right circular polarised photons, what is the overall polarisation of the beam?

I can guess either unpolarised or linear polarisation.

(Not homework: genuine question out of curiosity).

Comment: If it is linear, in which direction would it be?

Comment: But EACH photon is circularly polarised.

Comment: Unpolarized.   A 50-50 mix of LHC and RHC photons is mathematically equivalent to a 50-50 mix of any two orthogonal polarizations.  It has to be described by a so-called density matrix.  The eigenvalues of the density matrix can be used to distinguish between a mixture and a pure state:  50-50 versus 100-0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on whether the photons are entangled or not.

**Nonentangled Photons**

This is the case that in classical optics is described as depolarized light or, if the ratios are other than 50:50, partially polarized light.

In this case, the light is a classical mixture of two pure quantum states and each photon has a [von Neumann entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy) is exactly one bit per photon. In classical optics words, the light is said to be perfectly *depolarized*; a 50:50 mixture maximizes the entropy, the [degree of polarization, as discussed in my answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/377836/26076) is nought and the density matrix is $\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{id}$. Other probabilities in the mixture give us partial polarization with a nonzero degree of polarization. A probability mix of $p:1-p$ give us a lower von Neumann entropy and the degree of polarization is then $\frac{1}{2}-\min(p,\,1-p)$.

**Entangled Case**

Suppose that the photons are entangled in pairs. Now we have *bipartite* or two particle states. In this case one cannot talk in terms of the usual Jones or Mueller calculus nor in terms of everyday polarization because the quantum state space is four dimensional. Recall that all these polarization tools apply to a two dimensional Hilbert space (Jones matrices act on $2\times 1$ column vectors, for example). The new Hilbert space is spanned by the vectors $|L\,L\rangle$, $|L\,R\rangle$, $|R\,R\rangle$ and $|R\,L\rangle$. The augmented Jones calculus now acts on $4\times 1$ vectors, the augmented Jones matrices are members of the group ${\rm SU}(4)$, density matrices are $4\times 4$ Hermitian matrices and the augmented Stokes vectors are *sixteen* dimensional (being the dimension of the space of $4\times4$ Hermitian density matrices).

Now it could be that all the entangled pairs are in precisely the same quantum state, say $|L\,R\rangle$ or $|R\,L\rangle$. In this case, the quantum state is pure; you might even say perfectly polarized but this latter term is not advisable as it would confuse most people.

But we could equally well have classical mixtures of pure pairwise entangled states; in this case you can work out a generalized 16-dimensional Stokes vector and a corresponding degree of pureness and/ or von Neumann entropy. In your 50:50 case, only the states $|L\,R\rangle$ and $|R\,L\rangle$ are present, so you could now use a $2\times 2$ density matrix and a 4-dimensional Stokes/ Mueller calculus to describe the situation, but the basis states that this calculus would describe are quite different from those usually described in this way.

Comment: von Neumann entropy means you are using the density matrix. I am not saying I perform a measurement of the polarisation of the photons and do not look at the result, so that this is now 50% probably of being L or R. I'm saying that I overlap two beams of certain R and L polarisation onto the same beam. Are the two statements the same? Should I use the density matrix also for my example?

Comment: Also, if I put a conductive plate, which direction (<=> incident polarisation) will the current flow in?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I have something.

1) if single photons are observed, then we’ll see 50% L and 50% R.

2) if field sensitive measurements are performed, like the direction of the current in a conductive plate, the a linear polarisation will be observed. The angle will depend on the phase difference between the two fields.